# nested workspace problems: packages with the same name seem to overwrite?

Tags: python, bazel

I am working on a project where I need nested workspaces--our project has a git repository with a submodule, and both need to be able to build and run bazel tests independently.

The structure is like this:

```
projectA
    WORKSPACE
    tools/
        py/
          testing.py
    tests/
        sample_test.py
    projectB
        WORKSPACE
        tools/
           py/
              different_file.py
```

The file, sample_test.py, references both `projectA/tools/py/testing.py` and `projectB/tools/py/different_file.py`.

My projectA workspace has a config like this:

```
local_repository(
  name = "projectB",
  path = __workspace_dir__ + "/projectB",
)
```

And then my build rule for my test is like this:

```
py_test(
    name = "sample_test",
    srcs = ["sample_test.py"],
    deps = [
        ":class_under_test",
        "//tools/py:testing",
        "@projectB//tools/py:different_file",
    ]
)
```

And testing.py has imports like this:

```
from tools.py.testing import functionA
from projectB.tools.py.different_file import functionB
```

Now, when I run the test, I get a Python error that says:

```
ImportError: no module named tools.py.testing
```

If I comment out both imports and just say

```
import tools.py
```

and in my test setup, do `print(tools.py)`, it shows the path to testing in `projectB`!

```
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/analysis/py/test_name.runfiles/projectB/tools/py/__init__.pyc
```

The right thing seems to be here at:

```
bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/analysis/py/test_name.runfiles/__main__/tools/py/testing.py
```

What am I missing here? Surely there's a way for nested workspaces to be able to reference same paths without clobbering one another.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: For one thing, you show that your Project A workspace config makes references only to Project B.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're pointing out. Project A references both files in project A and project B. Project B makes no references to project A. Does that clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem resolved itself when I gave projectA a name in the workspace file:

```
workspace(name = "projectA")
```

I already had that line in projectB's WORKSPACE file but it got skipped in projectA.